# How to submit a form when it's action= is created outside it

Tags: jquery

I have this form that's a simple topsearch bar like below. There's no submit button. It get submitted when a user hits enter.

```
<form style="display:inline;" method="GET" action="/printers/" class="searchForm">
<input placeholder="Hit enter to search..." type="text" class="topsearchbar" value="">
</form>
```

Then comes the jQuery. This is where I take the value from the search box and add it to the current action and need to submit it. But I just cannot figure how to do this. Can you please help?

Here's my jquery:

```
$(".searchForm").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var action = ($(".searchForm").attr("action"));
var searchStr = ($(".topsearchbar").attr("value"));


if((action && searchStr) != '' &&  (action && searchStr).length >= 5)
{
alert('Ok to proceed')

var serverStr = action+'/'+searchStr;
alert(serverStr)
//Submit the form to serverStr. serverStr is the form's action

}
else
{
alert('To small to be any good')
}

}),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.searchForm').submit(function(event) {

        var $this = $(this),
            action = $this.attr('action'),
            query = $this.find('.topsearchbar').val(); // Use val() instead of attr('value').

        if (action.length >= 5 && query.length >= 5) {

          // Use URI encoding
          var newAction = (action + '/' + encodeURIComponent(query));
          console.log('OK', newAction); // DEBUG

          // Change action attribute
          $this.attr('action', newAction);

        } else {
          console.log('To small to be any good'); // DEBUG

          // Do not submit the form
          event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdnbW/).

Comment: There's a lot that's wrong. $(".searchForm").submit(function(event) this is causing it submit over and over again when I use the answer below:-)

Answer (score 0):

you also can change the action attribute like this

```
jQuery('.searchForm').attr('action', 'new-value');
```

if you do so...

```
jQuery('.searchForm').submit(function() {
    // ...you have to return 'true' if you want to submit after your code
    return true;
    // ...and 'false' if you want to stop the submit.
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Isnt it the same `$(".searchForm").submit`?

Comment: @Morpheus jQuery OR $ is both ok. ' OR " is both OK. submit is a property (Javascript) and submit() is a jQuery-Function. What do you mean exactly???

Comment: @Morpheus sorry, I had overlooked that at beginning, but now my answer is corrected, thanks.

Comment: Hang on a sec. I need to do something about this part jQuery('.searchForm').submit(function(). Each time the form submits it'll go thru this fucntion again and again

Comment: @Norman Create a jsfiddle to reconstruct the problem. Then I can help you. Maybe try to comment out the line with .preventDefault()

Comment: @Norman when do you call you code. A submit reloads the page, then you make the next submit with you function that's loaded again ;)

Answer (score 0):

On keydown events find the `enter==13` and  when everything is ok then submit the form.

```
$('.topsearchbar').keydown(function(e){ 

if(e.which==13){
  var action = $(".searchForm").attr("action");
  var searchStr = $(".topsearchbar").attr("value");


  if((action && searchStr) != '' &&  (action.length && searchStr.length) >= 5){
     alert('Ok to proceed');
     $(".searchForm").submit();
     var serverStr = action+'/'+searchStr;
     alert(serverStr);
     //Submit the form to serverStr. serverStr is the form's action

  }
   else
  {
  alert('To small to be any good')
  }
  }
});
```